# Rails: Creating models from existing tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have tables already created from a different project. Their names are formatted like aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd (all non plural and some parts aren't a convention word). I have successfully created a schema from the database by reading [this](http://blog.joelberghoff.com/2013/02/06/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-creating-a-rails-instance-from-an-existing-mysql-db/). But now I have to make the actual models. I've looked at [RMRE](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rmre/0.0.8/frames), but they enforce the ActiveRecord convention on my tables and change their names, which I don't want to do because other apps depend on those tables.

What is the best way to automatically create models and a schema from existing tables?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

just a **theory**, not sure how this would work in real app:

create `models` named as `ActiveRecord` convention requires, for example for table `aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd` you'll create a model `AaaBbb` and map this model to your table:

```
class AaaBbb < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd"
end
```

or a more human example:

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "my_wonderfull_admin_users"
end
```

Now you'll have `AaaBbb` as resource in routes meaning you'll have a url like:

```
 .../aaa_bbb/...
```

and if you want to use the table name name in url I guess you could rewrite the route:

`get 'aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd/:id', "aaa_bbb#show", as: "aaa_bbb"`

again, just a theory that might help you out. I haven't worked with such cases yet but would've start from this.

---

**edit**

to **automate** model creation from database:

https://github.com/bosko/rmre

but I think this will create models by rails convention with wierd names that you'll have to use as resource in your app.

---

A good template that I found on SO in case you want to use a model name different from table name:

```
class YourIdealModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'actual_table_name'
  self.primary_key = 'ID'

  belongs_to :other_ideal_model, 
    :foreign_key => 'foreign_key_on_other_table'

  has_many :some_other_ideal_models, 
    :foreign_key => 'foreign_key_on_this_table', 
    :primary_key => 'primary_key_on_other_table'
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to automate this from a schema.rb? I have ~20 tables with ~10 columns each.  Don't want to code names and attributes by hand if possible.

Comment: you should care about the tables only and use their columns as they are. I am not sure you can change the columns somehow without affecting the other app that works with this db. About automate I'll think a bout.. will update my answer if I find something usefull.

Comment: oh, i wasn't thinking about changing the column names. It's just right now I don't even have a models file since I'm doing stuff backwards.  So I'll have to type everything including `attr_accessible` stuff, so I'd want something to automatically generate ALL the model code for me.

Comment: Is backtick (`\``) used on purpose when setting table name?

Comment: @BruceSun I am pretty sure it should be comma.

Answer (score -3):

Just switch from Rails to Django and make
your life happier and also make your work normal:

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb my_table_without_existing_model > some_new_model.py
```

That's enough. Two seconds of work :)