# SQL File to Model in Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server

I'm wondering what the best way for a Ruby on Rails application to interact with an existing SQL file. Specifically, I have a database stored on a SQL 2008 Server and I want my application to be able to generate a Ruby model of the database (or part of the database).

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: Creating models from existing tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196912/rails-creating-models-from-existing-tables)

Answer (score 0):

What I understood: You have a SQL query in a file and want to run that SQL query against your application's database.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.complex_query
    find_by_sql(File.read(Rails.root.join('path', 'to', 'file.sql')))
  end
end

Foo.complex_query # return an array of objects representing result from the db
```